# Ordering the columns in the output of mapping task in Informatica cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I'm creating a mapping task to union,join 5 flat files and few transformation logic on top of it using Informatica cloud. I'm passing the output as .txt / .csv format for downstream processing and loading it to a data warehouse in certain column order.

I have to generate the output file during runtime because Liaison connection automatically cuts the output file which I'm dropping and pastes it inside data warehouse. (So I cannot use meta data and field mapping)

Is there any tool in the design which I can use to order the column sequence on the output (Like Column A should be the first column, Column C should be the second, Column B should be the third)

If there is no tool / object readily available inside the design pane of mapping task, is there any work around to do the same

Comment: Its little confusing. Informatica generates file(s) as per target design format. If you want that to be a particular sequence, you can easily modify targert design. If you want to change it frequently then that will be an issue. You may have to use some script.

Comment: I want that to be a particular sequence. How to modify the target design, can you guide me on the that?

Comment: Of course. I do not have cloud access right now, but you can refer to this image. Please click on 'Target Fields'  to modify the sequence.  http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-SAS1-w8wkpw/VVWG7wCy8EI/AAAAAAAAA5w/aWhsJ07-vVU/s1600/target_parameteriazes.png

Comment: Thanks Koushik, but for me the problem is I cannot have meta data as the automation process cuts the file and drops it in another location once the output is created, is there any other way apart from mapping meta data to sequence the column order?

Comment: can you run a script like shell script ? You can easily rearrange your columns using awk like this - awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {print $2, $1, $5, $3, $4}' in_file

Comment: Thanks for the details, is there any provision to type shell script in the target design? Kindly let me know

Comment: click on target and setup a sh script etc. depending on the target server. here is some example.